# Weird: Calling python method makes it run twice

Tags: python, python-import

Could anyone explain me why method run runs twice with this code:

```
import importlib
import sys


def load(module, className):
    if module not in sys.modules:
        module = importlib.import_module(module)
    else:
        module = sys.modules[module]

    loaded_class = getattr(module, className)
    return loaded_class()

class P:
    pass

class A:
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        print("s", kwargs)  # this runs twice


cc = load("app.tests.manual.wf", "A")
cc.run(event=P())
```

It loads module and then calls class method. It should run once but it returns:

```
s {'event': <app.tests.manual.wf.P object at 0x7fc42f2b1450>}
s {'event': <__main__.P object at 0x7fc42f29bc50>}
```

Comment: it seems to me that it first runs `P()` and then it runs what `P()` returns which is pretty normal or maybe that is not really the case here actually at which point I don't exactly know why this may happen

Comment: @Matiiss But what does `P` return? It's an empty class.

Comment: So? it doesn't matter if it is empty it will still be an object and will probably return itself, it is kinda similar in a way with functions that don't use `return`, they will return None. You can easily test this out Yourself. Just create an empty class with just `class Test:` and then `pass` and then just `print(Test())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Runs once *when it is imported* using importlib.import_module(module) (because you didn't make the final lines conditional like `if __name__ == '__main__':`)

Runs second time as part of the regular code.

You can see this because the two module names are different `app.tests.manual.wf` and `__main__` in your output.